# validating results from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, validation

I am trying to validate my results I get from an SQL query and to check if zero results are returned i am trying to echo an appropriate message. However i am struggling to do this any ideas i was trying to use if statements but wasn't working. Below is my code.

```
<?php
$mysql_query = "SELECT ISO_id, country_name, population, gdp, gold, silver, bronze, total FROM Country WHERE ISO_id='$countryID'";
$runmysql_query=mysql_query($mysql_query);

echo "<table class = 'table' border='4' align = 'center'>
<tr class = 'title'>
<th>ISOid</th>
<th>Country Name</th>
<th>Population</th>
<th>GDP</th>
<th>Gold</th>
<th>Silver</th>
<th>Bronze</th>
<th>Total</th>
</tr>"; //title headings declared

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($runmysql_query))
{
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td class = 'results'>" . $row['ISO_id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td class = 'results'>" . $row['country_name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td class = 'results'>" . $row['population'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td class = 'results'>" . $row['gdp'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td class = 'results'>" . $row['gold'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td class = 'results'>" . $row['silver'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td class = 'results'>" . $row['bronze'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td class = 'results'>" . $row['total'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>"; 
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: you could use the mysql num rows function. Then if 0 rows are returned, print the message, or else print the data. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php but mysql is deprecated so you should use mysqli

Comment: Please, don't use mysql_* functions - they are deprecated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$mysql_query = "SELECT ISO_id, country_name, population, gdp, gold, silver, bronze, total FROM Country WHERE ISO_id='$countryID'";
$runmysql_query=mysql_query($mysql_query);

$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($runmysql_query);
if($num_rows > 0)
{
//print table with rows
}
else
{
    print "no data";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the while loop's ugly step sister the `do...while`

```
if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($runmysql_query)){
    echo "<table>";
    do {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td class = 'results'>" . $row['ISO_id'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td class = 'results'>" . $row['country_name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td class = 'results'>" . $row['population'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td class = 'results'>" . $row['gdp'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td class = 'results'>" . $row['gold'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td class = 'results'>" . $row['silver'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td class = 'results'>" . $row['bronze'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td class = 'results'>" . $row['total'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>"; 
    } while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($runmysql_query));
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "<p>Nothing to see Here</p>";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Fairly simple, you'll be looking for something along the lines of this...

```
if(mysql_affected_rows() >= 1)
{
    // your while loop here
}
else
{
    // processing for no returned results
}
```

Comment: `mysql_affected_rows` is used for delete, insert, update, or replace. `mysql_num_rows` is used for select statements. See the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) for more info.

Comment: It appears mysql_* functions have now been depreciated.

Comment: That's not exactly new. They've been deprecated for several years now.

Comment: I'm aware of that now. My employer sent me on a course which taught me to use that function set!